# Too many data points on moisture data

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I create my graph with geom line I get this graph

[image]

Here is my code

```
ggplot(Moisture_kurokawa, aes(x = Date))+ geom_line(aes(y = W5, colour = "W5"))+ geom_line(aes(y = W7, colour = "W7"))+ geom_line(aes(y = W9, colour = "W9"))+ geom_line(aes(y = W11, colour = "W11"))
```

Any help on how to get it smoothen or see all the data points?

[My data file link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nulj8wqfifn1gxl/Moisture%20kurokawa.csv?dl=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take some time to read through some ggplot2 tutorials so you can let it do some of the work for you, especially if you do a bit of data rearranging.

You also need to have a proper date+time object for the resolution you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

Moisture_kurokawa <- read_csv("~/Data/Moisture kurokawa.csv")

mutate(Moisture_kurokawa, 
       timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time))) %>% 
  select(-Date, -Time) %>% 
  gather(W, value, -timestamp) -> moisture_long

moisture_long
## # A tibble: 17,645 x 3
##              timestamp     W value
##                 <dttm> <chr> <dbl>
##  1 2017-06-24 00:00:00    W5 0.333
##  2 2017-06-24 00:30:00    W5 0.333
##  3 2017-06-24 01:00:00    W5 0.334
##  4 2017-06-24 01:30:00    W5 0.334
##  5 2017-06-24 02:00:00    W5 0.334
##  6 2017-06-24 02:30:00    W5 0.334
##  7 2017-06-24 03:00:00    W5 0.335
##  8 2017-06-24 03:30:00    W5 0.335
##  9 2017-06-24 04:00:00    W5 0.335
## 10 2017-06-24 04:30:00    W5 0.335
## # ... with 17,635 more rows

ggplot(moisture_long, aes(timestamp, value, group=W, color=W)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

With your data in a better shape, you can even do:

```
ggplot(moisture_long, aes(timestamp, value, group=W, color=W)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~W)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will go through some tutorials

Answer (score 1):

```
Moisture_kurokawa <- read.table("Moisture kurokawa.csv", header=T, sep=",")

# Create a datetime object with as.POSIXct
Moisture_kurokawa$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(
    paste0(Moisture_kurokawa$Date, Moisture_kurokawa$Time), 
    format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(Moisture_kurokawa, aes(x = DateTime))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = W5, colour = "W5"))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = W7, colour = "W7"))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = W9, colour = "W9"))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = W11, colour = "W11"))
```

[image]